# Angular 2, how to depend on sizes or positions in the UI with ElementRef

Tags: angular

I have a paging component which has the input called "lastPage". I want to be able to draw the size of the "blue line", I need to know the size of an HTMLElement on the screen. I use an ElementRef and access the offsetWidth.

When changing the lastPage, the size of the gray area changes because the text on the right side changes too.
In dev mode, Angular 2 is not happy because the `detectChanges` is triggered multiple times and notices that the width of my blue line changed multiple times and got different value.

I get an error like this:
`platform-browser.umd.js:937 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '77.4'. Current value: '75'.`

How to get to depend on UI sizes as such. See the Plunkr.

https://plnkr.co/edit/CbAkmvSlyg7nsTSWJaBC

```
// Problematic code, this will trigger an error when I use [property]=getBubbleSize() 
private getBubbleSize(): number {
    return <number>this.slider.nativeElement.offsetWidth / this.lastPage;
}
```

I would like to avoid using the `ChangeDetectorRef`

Comment: What's the problem with `ChangeDetectorRef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `DoCheck`

```
export class PagerComponent implements DoCheck {
    @Input()
    lastPage: number = 1;

    @ViewChild('slider', { read: ElementRef })
    private slider: ElementRef;

    sliderWidth:number: 0;
    ngDoCheck() {
      this.sliderWidth = this.getBubbleSize();
      console.log('doCheck ' + this.sliderWidth);
    }

    private getBubbleSize(): number {
        return <number>this.slider.nativeElement.offsetWidth / this.lastPage;
    }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WSQ5uJTbaSKgVAsbJRz4?p=preview)

Comment: This is the best example. However, it is called quite often :(

Comment: It's called every time change detection is run. You have to ensure that what it does doesn't get too expensive. You can also use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to reduce the number of calls. Then you might have to take care yourself to notify Angular to run change detection.